# ASP.NET MVC - Why CSS is not working properly in Views? Button doesn't look even remotely the same

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

Why is CSS not working the same in Views as it would in some other HTML page?I made a button with different state properites,like hover and click and i copy and paste the same CSS to the site.css of the MVC project and add the proper classes to the html elements,but the results are completly different.

```css
.btn:link,
.btn:visited {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 100px;
  transition: all .2s;
}

.btn:hover {
  transform: translateY(-3px);
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}


/* When button is pressed */

.btn:active {
  transform: translateY(-1px);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.text-box {
  position: absolute;
  /* Positioning in reference to the parent   */
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  /* Positioning in reference to the element itself */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-box">

  <a href="#" class="btn btn-white">Discover our tours</a>

</div>
```

Comment: look in F12 Element tab --> css what append to your style(and if the css apply ) if you use bundle look if you load this style file

Comment: Well,it seems like btn class is being applied,but btn:visited and btn:link are not,is there a way to remove any kind of styling mvc is applying to the project?

Comment: to remove file you have to remove it from bundle or remove the link from the header (html header tag) also you can edit the css file

Comment: Ohh,i'm an idiot,i didn't know i have to also add the stylesheet link to the header,i thought MVC takes site.css as the stylesheet,it works as i wanted it now,thanks for the help :D

Comment: Can you just explain in short what is that bundle or where i can find the answer? I don't think i'm using it

Comment: it is not necessary but better way :https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/bundling-in-asp-net-mvc-application/

Comment: I will try to implement it then this way,thanks for the advice :)